# Webscraper Python Beautifulsoup

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I know what I'm trying to do is the simplest but it blows my mind. I'd like pull data from HTML page (https://partner.microsoft.com/en-us/membership/application-development-competency) using BeautifulSoup. To do that I need to use the .find() function I guess. Ain't know what to do no more. Appreciate every form of help.
Here's the HTML I'm working with:
[enter image description here][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/sHAMF.png

```html
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 

url = 'https://partner.microsoft.com/en-us/membership/application-development-competency'
res = requests.get(url)
html_page = res.content
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_page, 'html.parser')
text = soup.find("div",{"class":"col-md4[2]"})

output = ''
blacklist = [
    'style',
    'head',
    'meta',
    'col-md4[0]',
    'col-md4[1]',
]

for t in text:
    if t.parent.name not in blacklist:
        output += '{} '.format(t)

    sheet = '<html><body>' + text + '</body></html>';
    file_object  = open("record.html", "w+");
    file_object.write(sheet);
    file_object.close();
```

[enter image description here][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/sHAMF.png

Comment: you must use selenium for clicking on the drop-down so that the data can load using js then you can get the HTML as text from selenium then you can parse this string to HTML then you can scrape that data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this, but for this site i think better use XPath

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = 'https://partner.microsoft.com/en-us/membership/application-development-competency'
response = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, features="lxml")
cols = soup.find_all("div", class_="col-md-4")
print(cols[6].getText())
```